# Does gravity slow entropy?

Tags: general-relativity, soft-question

Just got to thinking about why time slows in a gravitational field. It occurred to me that, in a gravitational field, the closer you get to the source the slower time seems to travel. But also, the closer you are the more energy it takes to spread out. If we assume that time is a measure of increasing entropy, then it makes sense that it would slow closer to the source and go faster further away. Just wondering if this might be the mechanics of relativity.

Comment: Time slows down *with respect to an independent observer*, you'd still see 1 second ticking by at (what you perceive is) its normal rate.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the time coordinates for the different observers is entirely a geometrical effect, and is described by a geometrical object called the [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Metric_tensor).

Entropic arguments tend to be used to try and explain the flow of time i.e. the human perception that time flows from past to future. It is important to understand that the flow of time does not exist in relativity, or indeed in most of physics. Time is a coordinate, just like the spatial coordinates except with a different signature. The flow of time is unexplained, but may just be a quirk of human perception.